# Export STL from OpenSCAD command line, calling module within script?

Tags: openscad

Given a .SCAD file which contains some modules, how can I execute one of those modules from the command line?

**example.scad**

```
module One() { ... }
module Two() { ... }
```

**render.sh**

```
openscad -q -o one.stl --module One example.scad
```

Note that there is no `--module` option, but that is what I'm attempting to do. The workaround would be to make another .SCAD file e.g. `one.scad` which includes `example.scad`, and simply calls `One();` within and render that file from the shell file. But this is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `openscad -D` option can actually include arbitrary code, not just variable definitions, so you can include a call to the module.   You can even use `/dev/null` on Linux or NUL on Windows as the input file and have 100 % of your code in `-D` statements.

Comment: Maybe showing how exporting the STL works would benefit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSCAD doesn't have such an option on the command line, but the general idiom I believe you want to use is have `.scad` source files which are modules include invocations of the module(s) at the top-level controllable by variables you can set on the command line or GUI customizer interface. Any such invocations will be ignored if the file is used (via `use` directive) in another file so they don't hurt its status as a library and make it easier to preview/test. So for example you could have:

```
wantOne = false;
if (wantOne) One();
```

and then set `wantOne` to `true` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks. I think that is better than having a separate .scad just to call each module.

Answer (score 1):

elaborating on the answer from @r-github-stop-helping-ice, I find the following pattern useful:

###### example.scad

```
module a() { .. }
module b() { .. }
module c() { .. }

module print(item=0) {
  if (item==1) a();
  if (item==2) b();
  if (item==3) c();
}

item = 0;
print(item);
```

###### render.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}; do
  openscad -D item=${i} -o item_${i}.stl example.scad
done
```